# reg exp to validate range between numbers

Tags: regex

Need to use reg exp to check range between numbers. Valid value is 1-999999.

I've tried this without success:

```
^[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]{1,2,3,4,5,6}$
```

Anyone knows where i'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's the reason for using a regular expression instead of a simple comparison? I doubt that `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` is valid in any dialect. What is is supposed to do?

Comment: 1,2,3,4,5,6 is number of digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were close, but your quantifier is broken. To specify that the preceeding character, character class, or group must appear between *n* and *m* times, use `{n,m}`.

For example:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{0,5}$
```

This will match a string that consists of a single digit between 1 and 9, followed by up to 5 digits between 0 and 9.

Comment: this won't match numbers with leading zeroes.

Comment: @1010 I believe that's the point. OP isn't entirely clear on the requirements, but based on what's been provided I believe the intent is to only match numbers without leading zeros.

Comment: if it's an assignement I agree with you. if he's going to check user input I would suggest a less restrictive expression.